# Eslint no-unused-vars not detecting when export

Tags: eslint

I have this code:

```
const notUsed = 1;
export const notUsedExported = 1;
```

I'm not using those const, but when I run Eslint on that file I only get the error for the not exported const:

```
/Users/XXX/myproject/src/myFile.js
  38:7  error  'notUsed' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

Why is that? I want to get an error on the exported not used const also.

In my config of Eslint I have:

```
 {
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "semistandard",
    "plugin:jest/recommended"
  ],
  "env": {
    "es2019": true,
    "jest": true,
    "mocha": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "globals": {
    "Atomics": "readonly",
    "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  },
  "rules": {
    "array-callback-return": "warn",
    "camelcase": "warn",
    "guard-for-in": "off",
    "jest/no-conditional-expect": "warn",
    "jest/no-disabled-tests": "warn",
    "jest/no-focused-tests": "error",
    "jest/no-identical-title": "error",
    "jest/no-mocks-import": "warn",
    "n/no-path-concat": "off",
    "no-await-in-loop": "off",
    "no-case-declarations": "off",
    "no-console": "warn",
    "no-continue": "off",
    "no-control-regex": "warn",
    "no-empty-pattern": "off",
    "no-mixed-operators": "warn",
    "no-param-reassign": "off",
    "no-restricted-syntax": "off",
    "no-throw-literal": "warn",
    "no-underscore-dangle": "off",
    "no-unsafe-optional-chaining": "warn",
    "no-useless-escape": "warn",
    "prefer-regex-literals": "off",
    "promise/param-names": "off",
    "no-unused-vars": "error"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `export` is a usage of that variable, so it's not going to get picked up by `no-unused-vars`. To detect dead exports, you'll need either a third-party tool, or a plugin: `eslint-plugin-import` has [exactly the rule you need](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/no-unused-modules.md#rule-details).